# Wake-on-LAN with BusyBox?

Tags: busybox, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to implement the wake-on-lan magic packet in bash? I'm using a old, customized BusyBox and don't have `ether-wake`. Is it possible to replace it with some other shell command, like:

```
wakeonlan 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Comment: [wakeonlan](http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/jpo/software/wakeonlan/), although it seems to require perl which probably isn't in your busybox.

Comment: if you are able to use `python` see http://code.activestate.com/recipes/358449-wake-on-lan/ and put `alias` for this in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Since BusyBox has a lot of configuration options, you should tell us what you have. Also, are you sure that you have bash? Bash and BusyBox is an extremely unusual combination.

Comment: GNU bash, version 2.05a.0(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need something that's capable of sending an Ethernet packet that will be seen by the device you want to wake up.

The `ether-wake` command in BusyBox is exactly what you're after. If your BusyBox doesn't have it, consider recompiling BusyBox to include it.

If you have a sufficiently “bloaty” netcat (BusyBox can have one of two `nc` implementations, one of which handles TCP only), you can send a manually crafted UDP packet to the broadcast address of the network segment that the device is connected to.

```
mac=$(printf '\xed\xcb\xa9\x87\x65\x43') # MAC = ed:cb:a9:87:65:43
wol_packet=$(printf "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac$mac")
echo "$wol_packet" | nc -u 7 192.0.2.255
```

Another BusyBox utility that you could abuse into sending that packet is `syslogd`.

```
syslogd -n -O /dev/null -l 0 -R 192.0.2.255/7 &
syslogd_pid=$!
logger "$wol_packet"
kill $!
```

If the MAC contains a null byte, you won't be able to craft the packet so easily. Pick a byte that's not `\xff` and that's not in the MAC, say `\x42` (`B`), and pipe through `tr`.

```
echo "$wol_packet" | tr B '\000' | nc -u 7 192.0.2.255
```

If you really have bash (which is extremely unusual on devices with BusyBox — are you sure you really have bash, and not another shell provided by BusyBox?), it can send UDP packets by redirecting to `/dev/udp/$hostname/$port`.

```
echo "$wol_packet" >/dev/udp/192.0.2.255/7
```

Comment: My nc doesn't support -u; syslogd doesn't support -l; finally I don't have /dev/udp devices. :(

Comment: And yes, I have bash, check my comment above.

Comment: @michelemarcon Your strange device seems to lack the fundamental component of every method I can think of. I recommend compiling and uploading a binary (a more complete BusyBox, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/udp` is recognized by bash and doesn't really exist in the filesystem, so give it a try.

I think you can use `syslogd` without `-l` switch, as long as it supports `-R`.

I have busybox with `syslogd` withount `-R`, no `nc` nor `bash` and I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ssh server running on old HTC dream. My version of busybox also didn't include ether-wake and I'm not skilled enough to compile my own busybox. 
Fortunately I managed to wake up my PC using:

```
bash
cat mac2.txt | tr B '\000' >/dev/udp/192.0.1.255/7
```

Notice that the broadcast ip is different in my network.

I crafted the file (mac2.txt) containing the magic packet on my PC and pushed it to the server via SFTP. Because my mac has null byte I have to use tr to substitute all x42 bytes with 00. 
It worked like charm.

Comment: Why the [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)?